# What is One-to-one and one-to-many means in request/response?

Tags: asynchronous, language-agnostic, client-server

I'm a beginner and it's the first time i hear this word outside the database world. So what does this means here:

> In this case, yes.  Generators are nice when there is a **one-to-one 
>   relationship between requests and responses**, but when there is a 
>   **one-to-many** fanout as seen here (or similar situations that arise with the 
>   streaming_callbacks seen elsewhere in Tornado), I think it's cleaner to 
>   just use callbacks than to try and fit everything into a generator.

Can you provide some application that uses one-to-one and one-to-many?

Answer (score 1):

It's about database relationships, how an entry can be related to another or to many others.

For example, you have an User table and a Settings table.

One user is related to one settings entry. That's one to one.

Same think with table User and table articles:

One user wrote many articles. That's one to many.

You could try to read this:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships/

I hope it helped.

Comment: Well, one to many: u request every articles written by "john". Somethin like "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE user_id = 1; (where id 1 is John id) then u get all the articles.

Comment: Well your apache is usually used along a DB, otherwise I don't see any other exemples...

Comment: no, Apache is only an application server, not a database server, you can serve HTML without SQL ;)
the quote in the question is from Tornado, an event driven webserver